# How do you create an invisible button that covers the whole screen including navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a simple tableview that navigates to a detailed view with a navigation controller. In the detailed view I need to create a button which when pressed isolates all other buttons displayed on the screen including the navigation controller back button. I know how to get the invisible button to cover most of buttons the screen but I can't get it to cover the navigation controller back button as this has been created in the parent view. How do I pop it over the top of the navigation controller from the detail view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the button as a direct subview of the key window.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:theButton];
```

(why not use an UIAlertView or UIActionSheet?)

Comment: Thanks. This is a two stage button like the one used for App purchases on the App store. So first tap launches the isolating button (invisible) then the second tap on the same button with different color and text launches the AlertView. The invisible button cancels the action.